# Lista anidadas de provincias y cantones en mvc 5 con modelo de base de datos ado entities

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Buenas estoy haciendo un insertar provincia y cantón que están anidados, osea si selecciono una provincia me deben salir sus respectivos cantones, ya logré hacer que me retorne las provincias pero los cantones no sé como hacerlo. Muestro mi ccódigo actual:

**provincias controller:**

```
using LAB03.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace LAB03.Controllers
{
    public class ProvinciasController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Provincias
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var list = new List<spConsultarProvincias_Result>();
            using (PV2021C3_Lab03Entities db = new PV2021C3_Lab03Entities())
            {
                list = db.spConsultarProvincias().ToList();
            }

            return View(list);
        }
        public ActionResult CrearProvincia(int? id)

        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Agregar Provincia";
            if (id != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Title = "Editar Provincia";
            }
            Provincia pProvincia = null;
            using (PV2021C3_Lab03Entities db = new PV2021C3_Lab03Entities())
            {
                pProvincia = db.spConsultarProvincias()
                        .Where(a => a.idProvincia == id)
                        .Select(a => new Provincia { nombre = a.provincia, idProvincia = a.idProvincia, fechaCreacion = a.fechaCreacion, estado = a.estado })
                        .FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return View(pProvincia);

        }
        public ActionResult Guardar(Provincia pProvincia)

        {
            try

            {

                using (PV2021C3_Lab03Entities db = new PV2021C3_Lab03Entities())
                {
                    if (pProvincia.idProvincia == 0)
                    {
                        db.spCrearProvincia(pProvincia.nombre, DateTime.Now);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.spEditarProvincia(pProvincia.idProvincia, pProvincia.nombre, pProvincia.estado);
                    }

                }

                return View("GuardadoExitoso");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                return View("Error");

            }
        }
        public ActionResult EliminarProvincia(int? id)


        {
            try
            {
                var list = new List<spConsultarProvincias_Result>();
                using (PV2021C3_Lab03Entities db = new PV2021C3_Lab03Entities())
                {
                    db.spEliminarProvincia(id);
                    list = db.spConsultarProvincias().ToList();
                }
                return View("Index", list);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return View("Error");

            }


        }
        public ActionResult RetornaProvincia()
        {
            var provincias = new List<spConsultarProvincias_Result>();
            using (PV2021C3_Lab03Entities db = new PV2021C3_Lab03Entities())
            {
                provincias = db.spConsultarProvincias().ToList();
            }
            return Json(provincias);
        }
        public ActionResult RetornaCantones(int idProvincia)
        {
            var cantones = new List<spConsultarCantonesPorProvinciaId_Result>();
            using (PV2021C3_Lab03Entities db = new PV2021C3_Lab03Entities())
            {
                cantones = db.spConsultarCantonesPorProvinciaId(idProvincia).ToList();
            }
            return Json(cantones, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
}
```

**vista crear provincia:**

```
@model LAB03.Models.Provincia


<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<form action="/Provincias/Guardar" method="post">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(_ => _.idProvincia, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "hidden" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(_ => _.estado, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "hidden" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(_ => _.fechaCreacion, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "hidden" })
   
  
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row-cols-md-2 control-label ">Provincias</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select name="provincia" id="provincias" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="row-cols-md-2 control-label ">Cantón</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select type="canton" id="valCanton" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
    </div>


    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    <a href="/Provincias/Index" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn" style="color:darkred" id="btnelim">Eliminar</button>
</form>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function cargarSelectListaProvincias()
    {
        var url = '/Provincias/RetornaProvincia';
        var parametros = {};

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(parametros),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr)
            {
                construirSelect(data);
                //console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jQxhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    };

    function construirSelect(data)

    {
        var ddlProvincias = $('#provincias');
        ddlProvincias.empty();

        var optionDefault = "<option value=''>Selecione una Provincia</option>"
        ddlProvincias.append(optionDefault);

        $(data).each(function () {
            var provincia = this;
            var option = "<option value='" + provincia.id + "'>" + provincia.provincia + "</option>";
            ddlProvincias.append(option);
        });
    };
    function setEvents()

    {
        $('#provincias').change(function () {
            var id = $('#provincias').val();
            $('#valCanton').val(id);
        });

    };

    setEvents();
    cargarSelectListaProvincias();
    
    </script>
```

**vista index:**

```
@model List<LAB03.Models.spConsultarProvincias_Result>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Lista de Provincias</h2>
<br>

<a href="/Provincias/CrearProvincia" class="btn btn-primary">Agregrar Provincia </a>

<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Provincia</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Fecha Creacion</th>
        <th>Editar</th>
        <th>Eliminar</th>
    </tr>

    @{
        foreach (LAB03.Models.spConsultarProvincias_Result provincia in this.Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <th>@provincia.idProvincia</th>
            <th>@provincia.provincia</th>
            <th>@provincia.estado</th>
            <th>@provincia.fechaCreacion.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</th>
            <th><a href="~/Provincias/CrearProvincia?id=@provincia.idProvincia" class="btn btn-primary">Editar Provincia</a></th>
           <th> <a href="~/Provincias/EliminarProvincia?id=@provincia.idProvincia" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar Provincia</a></th>
        </tr>


        }

    }
</table>
```

Tengo el modelos de la base de datos en sql server, es esta:

Agradezco la ayuda.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Sección 1.10.32 de "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", escrito por Cicero en el 45 antes de Cristo
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"